# Cannot install mysql server on Debian 11

Tags: mysql, dependencies, debian

I have installed MySQL APT Repository on my OS, then tried to execute the following command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

It shows me these errors:

```
$ sudo apt install mysqL-server
Reading package lists.. Done
Building dependency tree.. Done
Reading state information.. Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mariadb-client-core-10.5 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client-core
mariadb-server-core-10.5 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server-core
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver: :Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held
packages
```

I have never installed **mariadb** on my device. Why is this error reported? I need to install mysql server on my device.

Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040840/how-to-install-mysql-5-7-on-debian-11-bullseye/75041099#75041099

Answer (score 3):

remove mariadb with
apt remove mariadb-common
then install mysql did it for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo apt install default-mysql-server` to install it.